# Batch File Kill a stuck process(CPU utilization is zero)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, automation

I'm working in it company where I have to do one work manually everyday that I'm willing to automate

We have to monitor taskbar in every two hours for a process, if process have zero CPU utilization then we have to kill it else OK 
Please help me out to automate it.

Comment: I suppose you are aiming a particular process with known name? Because a lot of system processes could show `0%` load in the taskbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `notepad` to the process you want to watch:

```
@echo off

set "process_name=notepad.exe"

::remoce .exe suffix if there is
set pn=%process_name:.exe=%

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set c=0
:: getting three snapshots of CPU usage of the given process
for /f skip^=2^ tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%p in ('typeperf "\Process(%pn%)\%% Processor Time"  -sc 3') do (
    set /a counter=counter+1
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%%p") do set  "process_snapshot_!counter!=%%a%%b"

)

:: remove rem to see the cpu usage from the three snapshots
rem set process_snapshot_

:: if all three snapshots are less than 0000010 process will be killed
if 1%process_snapshot_1% LSS 10000010 if 1%process_snapshot_2% LSS 10000010 if 1%process_snapshot_3% LSS 10000010 (
     tskill %pn%
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have test it by taking notepad.exe and iexplorer.exe but script did not work, ie not able to kill process

Comment: @user3856852 what if you use `taskkill /im %pn%* /f` instead of `tskill %pn%` ?

Comment: not worked, could you try in your end and then change code accordingly :)

Comment: @user3856852  - I'm an idiot .Forgot set %-es at checking condion and instead of numbers I've compared strings.Now is fixed and tested with `notepad.exe`.